# How to listen to the cameraX lens facing changes

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-camerax

Does camerax provide api for lens facing changes callback? After switching the lens facing camera I want to be notified when it has finished changing and the camera is ready to use.

Currently I'm using this dependencies of camerax

```
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-beta01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha08"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-extensions:1.0.0-alpha08"
```

Comment: "After switching the lens facing camera". As far as I know, the lens can only be switched manually, by using a different camera selector. Shouldn't this be your signal?

Comment: yes and I want to receive the callback after the camera finishes the lens face changes, because it needs some amount of time to switch the camera from back to front  and vice versa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a signal for when the camera starts emitting frames. You can use `Camera2Interop` and set a `CaptureCallback` on the preview use case for example. After binding the preview use case using a `CameraSelector` for the lens facing you want, you can listen for when `onCaptureCompleted()` is invoked, this should give you a signal that the camera has started.

```
val builder = Preview.Builder()
Camera2Interop.Extender(builder).setSessionCaptureCallback(object: CameraCaptureSession.CaptureCallback() {
   override fun onCaptureCompleted(session: CameraCaptureSession, request: CaptureRequest, result: TotalCaptureResult) {
      // Camera will start emitting frames
   }
})
val preview = builder.build()
```