# Callback for bindCameraUseCases()

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to get an android camerax_version = '1.0.0-beta03' example working following the official camerax example. To start the Preview `viewFinder.post {bindCameraUseCases()}` is called.
Is it possible to get a callback when `bindToLifecycle` inside `bindCameraUseCases()` has finished?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for something similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61561964/how-to-listen-to-the-camerax-lens-facing-changes/61586714#61586714

Comment: Thank you. Your code snipped gets called after every frame, not only after the first frame. So it's a first step in the right direction, but it's producing unnecessary calls. Do you know if it can be modified to be only calles after the first frame?

Answer (score 0):

So with the hint of Husayn Hakeem I finally got what I want:

```
        Camera2Interop.Extender(builder).setSessionStateCallback(object: CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
        override fun onConfigureFailed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {}

        override fun onConfigured(session: CameraCaptureSession) {}

        override fun onActive(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
            Log.d("CameraX", "First Frame")
        }
        override fun onClosed(session: CameraCaptureSession) {
            Log.d("CameraX", "Last Frame")
        }
    })
```